Matching output format of YOLOv8 and face_recognition.face_location
This is my code:
results = model_yolo.predict(img, show=False)
for result in results:
    boxes = result.boxes.cpu().numpy()
    for box in boxes:
        xywh = box.xywh[0]
        x, y, w, h = map(int, xywh)
        yolo_boxes.append(tuple(xywh))
small_frame = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
rgb_small_frame = np.ascontiguousarray(small_frame[:, :, ::-1])
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
print(yolo_boxes)
print(face_locations)

and the output:
[(409.03186, 282.89722, 108.96521, 134.4579), 
(665.1231, 365.39087, 113.57483, 148.86255), 
(1057.6338, 239.82077, 306.38477, 319.76196), 
(135.80556, 622.28186, 270.69217, 327.43454), 
(528.89624, 247.344, 71.73767, 95.44037), 
(698.29346, 227.99313, 75.90662, 97.3443), 
(801.3705, 453.05206, 102.06665, 132.30774)]
[(78, 181, 114, 145), (121, 63, 196, 0), (54, 117, 90, 81)]

I want to match the output formats of yolo and face_locations.
I tried other formats offered by yolo, but it doesn't seem to give me the right format.

From the current code example it is unclear what framework/library you use for face recognition, what is face_recognition here? Please provide this information, so others can check the face_locations() method output format and help you with this problem.
